# fetch data from database through entity

Tags: jquery, entity-framework, highcharts

I try to use entity framework.
I have table in sql
i.e.

```
Catg_id  Catg_type
1       Medical
2       Engineering
3       Other
```

I tried this -

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProjectdbEntities a = new ProjectdbEntities();
            var b = a.Catg_type;
            foreach (var c in b)
            {
                string catname = c.Catg_type1;
            }

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static string jqufunc()
        {

        }
```

and I use highchairs for display charts
[image]

In above image,I want to display Medical , Engineering and other instead of Computer laptops other through entity 
in jquery -

```
$(function () {

        var webmethod = "WebForm1.aspx/jqufunc";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: webmethod,
            data:JSON.stringify({ s:"xyx" }),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    });


    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Computer info'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Computers', 'Laptops', 'Other ']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Figures'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Pentinum 4',
                data: [1, 0, 4]
            }, {
                name: 'Pentinum 3',
                data: [5, 7, 3]
            }, {
                name:'Core i7',
                data:[6,3,4]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Now I don't want hard code,I want to get data from database and display in chart through entity .. I code in page load but how to call this through function 
any solution?

Comment: Show me your Table Structure and SQL Query for the data

Comment: this is query ...select Std_info.Std_name ,Catg_type.Catg_type from Std_info
inner join Catg_type on Std_info.Catg_id=Catg_type.Catg_id

Comment: where is the **series data** coming from ??

Comment: So what is returned into JS? or do you have a problem with constructing required response on back end? As for Highcharts - you should create your chart after all data is successfully delivered. You could set categories in series data like here: http://jsfiddle.net/jgLodaub/ (However, pleas note that this way you are assigning names for points and not x values that are still automatically assigned as in your code with hard-coded data)